# Gamma distributed random variables in C++

Tags: c++, boost, random, gamma-distribution

What is the easiest way to get a gamma distributed random variable in C++? Boost seems to have this functionality, but it is not clear for me how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s pretty straightforward:

```
boost::mt19937 rng;
boost::gamma_distribution<> pdf(alpha);
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::gamma_distribution<> >
    generator(rng, pdf);
```

Constructs a random number generator and a [gamma distribution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/gamma_distribution.html) and glues them together into a usable generator. Now you can create random numbers by invoking the `generator`.

Comment: @stonybrooknick Unfortunately, [Boost doesn’t seem to have it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.distributions) but it shouldn’t be too hard to implement once you look at how the other distributions are implemented and how the PDF is defined.

Comment: @stonybrooknick: By "beta" you either mean a scale parameter or a rate parameter.  In the first case multiply the variates by beta, otherwise divide them.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you do it in C++11:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::mt19937 G;
    typedef std::gamma_distribution<> D;
    G g;  // seed if you want with integral argument
    double k = .5;      // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution
    double theta = 2.0;
    D d(k, theta);
    std::cout << d(g) << '\n';
}
```

Your compiler may or may not yet support `<random>`.  Boost random has just recently been modified to conform to the std::syntax, but I'm not sure if that modification has actually been released yet (or is still just on the boost trunk).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Gamma Distribution in Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526483/gamma-distribution-in-boost/2875317#2875317) has some code that will do what you want. The bit you're probably missing is `boost::variate_generator`.